# Is my issue Instagram API Platform Deprecation?

Tags: instagram-api

On a shopify site I've designed - www.ranasbakery.com The Instagram api is no longer displaying. Please note, I'm not the developer - he's too busy to get in touch with, hence the need for some help - also I don't think this is out of my realm, but damned if I can see where the answers lie.

Could this be this platform depreciation? There's a couple of paragraphs in the Instagram developer section that I don't fully understand that seem to possibly point to that as the reason. But how to resolve the issue doesn't seem to be anywhere to be seen.

It's just an API displaying the instagram feed. Has been fine until recently. I'd really appreciate some insights if anyone has any. I've turned off the instagram feed, but it says "The access_token provided is invalid. Check the Homepage - social feeds section in your theme settings."  The access token has been fine, up until now, what might have changed?

Huge advance thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to re-generate your OAuth Access Token. The Javascript attempts to load this URL:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/296922654/media/recent/?client_id=b9250ffaa750473497707f1f507165dd`

Which results in:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 400,
    "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
    "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."
  }
}
```